# Transit layover visa requirements for Indian citizen travelling to Turkey

Tags: planning, transit-visas

I am planning to travel from New Delhi to Turkey. The possible stopover choice for me are Bishkek, Riyadh, Almaty. Assuming the stopover is about 14 hours maximum, what are the transit visa requirements. Also what special care needs to be taken if one is wearing a religious headwear such as turban?

Comment: Those are in three separate countries, so separate visa requirements. I'd suggest you [refer to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens) to preliminarily plan your itinerary, and this site doesn't entertain such questions. Once you decide, you might ask a specific question about your religious concerns.

Comment: You may want to enter your details into a tool like [Timatic Web](http://www.flyslm.com/visa.html) and see the requirements for yourself. Once you have narrowed down to one transit point or have a concrete query about one of the countries, you can edit the question. Also as a side-note (though you probably know this already), there is a direct TK flight between DEL and IST